# How to set up routeEnhancers for a simple GET parameter?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to create a routeEnhancer for a simple GET parameter:

*/?pageNumber=1&cHash=...*

This parameter (including the cHash) is generated by the page browser of a multi-page sitemap (pure TypoScript), which can be simulated with the following simplified TypoScript:

```
page.10 = COA
page.10{
    10 = LOAD_REGISTER
    10{
        pageNumber.cObject = TEXT
        pageNumber.cObject.value = 0
        pageNumber.cObject.override.data= GP:pageNumber
        pageNumber.cObject.wrap = (|+1)
        pageNumber.prioriCalc = intval
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20{
        data = register:pageNumber
        typolink {
            parameter.data = TSFE:id
            additionalParams.data = register:pageNumber
            additionalParams.wrap = &pageNumber=|
        }
    }
}
```

Result (without routeEnhancers):

- On page 0 (the root page "/"): `<a href="/?pageNumber=1&amp;cHash=...">1</a>`
- On page 1: `<a href="/?pageNumber=2&amp;cHash=...">2</a>`
- On page 2: `<a href="/?pageNumber=3&amp;cHash=...">3</a>`

And so on. That works as expected, but I'd like to have nicer URLs.

My routeEnhancers attempt for rewriting the URLs:

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageBrowser:
    type: Simple
    routePath: '/page/{page_number}'
    requirements:
      page_number: '[0-9]'
    _arguments:
      page_number: 'pageNumber'
```

Result with this routeEnhancer:

- On page 0: `<a href="/page/1/">1</a>`
- On page 1 the link **unfortunately remains unchanged**: `<a href="/page/1/">1</a>`

It seems that the encoding works, but the decoding fails.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is some confusion with page_number and pageNumber:

I think this setup does, what you are looking for. (I had to manually delete cache too)

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = COA
page.10{
    10 = LOAD_REGISTER
    10{
        pageNumber.cObject = TEXT
        pageNumber.cObject.value = 0
        pageNumber.cObject.override.data= GP:pageNumber
        pageNumber.cObject.wrap = (|+1)
        pageNumber.prioriCalc = intval
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20{
        data = register:pageNumber
        typolink {
            parameter.data = TSFE:id
            additionalParams.data = register:pageNumber
            additionalParams.wrap = &pageNumber=|
        }
    }
}


routeEnhancers:
  PageBrowser:
    type: Simple
    routePath: '/page/{pageNumber}'
    requirements:
      pageNumber: '[0-9]+'
```

Comment: I thought you were looking for something like this. I did not question the use of it. Well, then I have no idea what you try to do :(

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question a bit to clarify it. It is about beautifying URLs with the new core feature "routeEnhancers", which work similar to the old RealURL.

Comment: I thought the GET parameter pageNumber was assigned to the argument page_number. I had chosen a different spelling to distinguish them from each other. Your example looks good, better than mine, but it results in links with a cHash attached to them: /page/2/?cHash=... Do you know how to to get rid of this? The docu says:  If the requirements are too loose, a URL signature parameter (“cHash”) is added to the end of the URL which cannot be removed.

Comment: `typolink.useCacheHash = false` should work to get rid of the cHash.

Comment: I see, the cHash does not come from the routeEnhancer, but from the typolink. I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work. Even if I remove the routeEnhancer and set useCacheHash to false, I still get a cHash. Do you think this is a bug, or am I still missing something? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like the routeenhancer overwrites it. Out of ideas :(